# can we restore data of table which are accidentally lost with the php artisan migrate command run on server in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

i am using migration for database in **Laravel** project and project is also running on server with live users
by accidentally i am run command **php artisan migrate** command on server and i am lost my live server  data of my tables on server is any idea which we use for this type of mistakes to prevent data lost.

Comment: restore from backup. You take frequent backups of your live database, right...?

Comment: If you have a backup, then restore the data from there. If you do not have a backup, well, that's it. Artisan migrate can be used to recreate the database structure, but not the lost data.

Comment: @ADyson right but i am asking about idea we can code something in migration when we going to rollback tables we can take backup of every table with the help of code ???

Comment: @Shadow yes you are right but any idea which we use to take backup when we rollback table ??

Comment: So, are you asking how to prevent the possibility of this happening, rather than asking how to restore some data you have already lost? If so, please clarify your question because the way you wrote it, it sounds like you already ran this command and lost your data, and are asking how to get it back. Your question asks how to restore data which was lost during migration...it does not not ask how to make a backup before running the migration. These are two totally different things.

Comment: yes i am not lost any of my data i am just asking both like if i am lost my data any idea to restore that data and second how we can take backup when we are rollback migrations.

Comment: You have to do the backup **before** you run a migration, so you can restore the data if the migration goes wrong. Doing a database backup is not a programming question, mysql has tools for that purpose. The DBA sister site of SO has several questions on this topic.

Comment: `if i am lost my data any idea to restore that data`...yes, restore a backup (as already mentioned). You can't magically re-create data which has been deleted. You need to make a copy of it **before** you delete it. `how we can take backup when we are rollback migrations` ...yes, make a shell script which runs the mysql backup command before it runs the php artisan command. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/8.0/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html . Did you do any research about this yourself?